# Change Markdown front matter on site build

Tags: javascript, gulp, yaml, markdown, netlify

I'm using Netlify cms and it creates the frontmatter as:

```
---
cover: /content/projects/birdnestsoup.jpg
date: '2018-09-10'
title: soup
tags: soup
---
```

however what I want is:

```
---
cover: './birdnestsoup.jpg'
date: '2018-09-10'
title: soup
tags: soup
---
```

I'm trying to use gulp to change all of the *.md files in a directory to remove /content/projects/ and instead just have ./ in the front matter under cover.

I'm open to any other solution, just so long as it can be done upon build.

Comment: Are you trying to edit your files once by modifying and saving the originals to disc or do you want to leave the originals as-is and have the modification happen repeatedly with every "build"? What have you tried, and how did that not address your needs?

Comment: I'd like to modify the file, no need to save the original. I'm wanting to have it run when the website is built using gatsby build because it rebuilds every time the netlify cms creates a post. I've tried just fixing it by changing where and how it writes the files but I cannot find a way for it to work.